# creating a new guid at each iteration in an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I try to script an ARM template like this:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/ipfilterrules",
    "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('name'), '/fr', copyIndex())]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",

    "properties": {
        "ipMask": "[parameters('ipMasks')[copyIndex()]]",
        "action": "Accept",
        "filterName": "[concat('fr', copyIndex())]"
    },
    "copy": {
        "name": "eventHubfirewallrulescopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('ipMasks'))]"
}
```

What I really want to to is to feed "name" and "filtername" by the same GUID value. in order to have something like this:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/ipfilterrules",
    "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('name'), 'd8fb1ab2-a6cb-439f-9354-918bd96d6ace')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",

    "properties": {
        "ipMask": "[parameters('ipMasks')[copyIndex()]]",
        "action": "Accept",
        "filterName": "d8fb1ab2-a6cb-439f-9354-918bd96d6ace"
    },
    "copy": {
        "name": "eventHubfirewallrulescopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('ipMasks'))]"
}
```

As you can see this is a multi deployement resource. So I need a new guid generated at each iteration.

I first thought to create a variable using guid() function, but it is not permitted.

Is there any other idea?
thank you

Comment: May I ask why don't you simply append copyIndex() to the name?

Comment: because it has to be unique

Comment: How about concat the name with a guid() that you save inside the variable section and then you append the copyIndex() output to it?

Comment: I can't because variables only accept deterministic function

Answer (score 2):

How about defining a proxy parameter in the template for which you do not pass the value and is initialed to default new guid and use it in the variables later to generate the unique string? Something like this

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
         "guidValue": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "unique_string":"[uniqueString(parameters('guidValue'))]"
    },
    "resources": 
    [
      .. your resources with names derived from variables('unique_string') 
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "unique_string": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('unique_string')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: the problem is that I have a copy {}. Each iteration will produce the same result. I can't set a copyIndex into a variables

Comment: well, in that case you can prefix or suffix the uniquely generated string with the copyIndex() something like this
"name":"[concat(variables('unique_string'),copyIndex())]",
"filterName":"[concat(variables('unique_string'),copyIndex())]"

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response

Answer (score 0):

If the length of parameters('ipMasks') is known you can use either a pregenerated array of guids with the same length and then use copyIndex to pick the guid in the same way that you pick the ip masks. If a random guid is needed (in my case a static guid was needed) the same scenario with a generated guid list should work:

```
[
            "[newGuid()]",
            "[newGuid()]",
            "[newGuid()]",
            "[newGuid()]",
            "[newGuid()]"
]
```

Assuming a fixed array parameter of 5 items.